# Maximization of quotient of quadratic forms

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, derivatives, optimization, quadratic-forms

I have a problem with finding:

$$\max_{a \in \mathbb{R}^p} \frac{a’Ca}{a’Ba},$$

where $C$ and $B$ are $p \times p$ symmetric matrices.

After differentiation I get the following result:

$$\frac{2a’C(a’Ba) - 2a’B(a’Ca)}{(a’Ba)(a’B’a)} =0$$

I can’t solve the above equation for $a$. How to find it?

Comment: @TSF I don't see the problem: we are multiplying a matrix by a scalar

Comment: In the case that $B$ is positive definite, we can write $B = M'M$ for some invertible matrix $M$, and the desired maximum will be the maximal eigenvalue of the symmetric matrix
$$
[M']^{-1}CM'
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Could you elaborate on this? I can’t see it.

Comment: I could, but I'd rather answer the question.  As it is currently asked, there is no guarantee that the maximum will exist.  Are we given some conditions on the matrices $A$ and $B$ (or on their quadratic forms)?

Comment: Actually it’s a linear regression problem. $B = (X’X)^{-1}$, where $X$ is a design matrix. However there is no condition on $C$.

Answer (score 4):

The maximum won't generally exist.  It can be guaranteed to exist, however, if $B$ is positive definite.

In this case, suppose that $B = M'M$ for some invertible matrix $M$ (we can compute $M$ via a Cholesky decomposition for instance).  We then have
$$
\max_a \frac{a'Ca}{a'Ba} = 
\max_a \frac{a'Ca}{a'M'Ma} = 
\max_a \frac{a'Ca}{(Ma)'(Ma)} \\
= \max_b \frac{(M^{-1}b)'C(M^{-1}b)}{b'b} 
= \max_b \frac{b'([M']^{-1}CM^{-1})b}{b'b}.
$$
By the Rayleigh-Ritz theorem, this maximum is the largest eigenvalue of $[M']^{-1}CM^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Denote the scalar which you wish to optimize as
$$\lambda = \frac{a^TCa}{a^TBa}$$
Take your gradient result, transpose it, multiply it by $\,\frac{a^TBa}{2},\,$ and write it as
$$Ca = \lambda Ba$$
This is a [generalized eigenvalue problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Generalized_eigenvalue_problem) and you want the eigenvector corresponding to the largest such eigenvalue.

If $\,B^{-1}$ exists, then this can be reduced to an ordinary eigenvalue problem for $L=B^{-1}C$. 
$$La = \lambda a$$

If $\,C^{-1}$ exists, then it becomes an eigenvalue problem for the *reciprocal* eigenvalues $\big(\mu=\frac{1}{\lambda}\big)$ of the matrix $M=C^{-1}B$. 
$$Ma = \mu a$$